# A Function as a collection of Arrows

Tags: category-theory

Normally you define a **function** to be a **map** on a **set**. But how about defining a function, in *Category Theory*, as a collection of **arrows**?

Take this cateogry

**Objects**: *true*, *false*.

**Arrows**:

```
true -> true
false -> false
true -> false
false -> true
```

Here I had to specify **FOUR** arrows, but I could summarize this collection of arrows as **TWO** functions:

```
id(x) = x    // replaces the first 2
not(x) = !x  //replaces the second 2
```

If you want to maintain "arrowhood", which is more categoric, you could write a meta-arrow

```
idArrow(x)  = x -> x
notArrow(x) = x -> not(x)
```

Either way you compress information.

### Question

Is there a strandard way of expressing these meta-arrows? Is this even part of the theory?

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 5):

You have a set $S$ being acted on by a group $G$, and you are constructing the corresponding [action groupoid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action+groupoid). This is a standard construction. By the way, you haven't fully specified a category yet, since you haven't specified how your arrows compose.

Comment: They compose as you would expect `(b -> c) * (a -> b) = (a -> c)`, just that I don't want to write out all the combinations. What I am saying is that instead of having to specify each arrow, and each composition rule, this is could be abstracted out by specifying its form without having to use sets and functions.

Comment: @Cristian: that's fine. Then your category is an action groupoid.

Answer (score 5):

Given any functor $F : X \to Y$, you can construct the category $Z$ defined by:

Start with the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$.

For each object $x \in X$ and arrow $F(x) \xrightarrow{f} y$, add an arrow $x \xrightarrow{(x,f)} y$.

Composition is

- $ g (x,f) = (X,fg)$ if $g : y \to y'$
- $ (x, f) g = (x', f F(g))$ if $g : x'\to x$

This construction has a name, but I forget what it's called. (bridge, maybe?)

Anyways, in the special case that $X$ and $Y$ are sets (i.e. all morphisms are identity morphisms), then $F$ is a function, and this gives a way to view $F$ as a bunch of arrows.

The motivation behind the choice of new arrows and composition law above is that we want to formally add arrows $x \to F(x)$, but have a commutative diagram

$$ \begin{matrix} x &\xrightarrow{f}& x'
\\ \downarrow & & \downarrow
\\ F(x) &\xrightarrow{F(f)}& F(x') \end{matrix}$$

All new arrows are thus an arrow in $X$ followed by one from $X$ to $Y$ followed by an arrow from $Y$. But using the diagram, we can rewrite every such arrow as simply one from $X$ to $Y$ followed by one in $Y$, and I've used that normalization in choosing the representation. We could normalize the other way as well (make the thing in $Y$ the identity arrow)

Comment: If memory serves, this is indeed called a bridge.

Comment: Having a hard time picturing it. How would you apply it to my example?

Comment: It is also called the *collage* of the profunctor $\hom(F-,-):X^{op}\times Y\to \mathcal Set$.

Comment: I would call it the mapping cylinder.